# Dynamically creating an Entry Input using .Net Maui

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows

I have a vertical stack layout that prompts a user; say "Do you have a car?" If the user clicks yes, I want an Entry to be displayed so the user can enter their make and model.

How do I dynamically create that input Entry? A link to the documentation would be appreciated as well.

Best,

I've tried using a collection view, because I can add an entry to the view, but that doesn't work.

Comment: There is a same thread posted at Q&A - ["How do i dynamically create an Entry on a vertical stack layout?"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1141665/how-do-i-dynamically-create-an-entry-on-a-vertical.html), let's focus on that one.

Answer (score 2):

to dynamically add an `Entry`

```
var ModelEntry = new Entry();
myStackLayout.Children.Add(ModelEntry);
```

however, another option would be to include the `Entry` in your XAML with its `IsVisible` set to `false`.  Then in your code you can do this

```
ModelEntry.IsVisible = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to use the XAML, but the user can also have multiple cars. so everytime the user clicks say a "Add" button, a new Entry is added to the view.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically add controls without breaking MVVM or am I forced to use code behind? When the number of elements created is not determined, or the total amount of controls is very large, the page loads slow. That is if you simply use their IsVisible properties and bind them to the viewmodel.